# Is there a verb that means "to visit a consulate/embassy to get some papers"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

That's a long shot, but is there a verb that means "to go to a consulate/embassy to get some paperwork done"?

For instance, as an Italian person:

- In Italy, to go to the Laos embassy to get a visa.
- In Laos, going to the Italian consulate to declare I have lost my Italian passport and need a new one or a replacement.

Preferably a single-word verb, in any case under 20 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, there is no single-word verb, or even a short phrase, that carries such a precise meaning. The only way round this problem that I can think of would be to *invent* a new word to convey this meaning, and to explicitly define it whenever it is used. For instance:

> In this document, the verb **docuvisit** is used to mean "to go to a consulate/embassy to conduct business involving official documentation". The noun **docuvisit** is used to reference a trip of this kind.